# How to use MVVM in AvalonDock 2.0

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, avalondock

I am developing a WPF app that requires Docking control.
I downloaded Telerik's RADDock but I understand it is not native MVVM control (Have I got to the right conclusion??)

So later I downloaded and installed Avalaon dock 2.0, which has built-in  MVVM support, however I can't understand how to use it..

I have a User control I created (Terminal control that encapsulates a TextBox) and I want to dynamically add new terminal instances to the AvalonDock LayoutDocumentPane, through my view model.

Can anyone please guide me through this, maybe supply a simple code example that demonstrates how this can be done.

Thanks in advance friends.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of info on how to use AvalonDock 2.0 in MVVM-style [on the net](http://bit.ly/1DAbRKV).

However, the most interesting ideas were proposed by [Ashley Davis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM). But his library works with AvalonDock 1.3, so it can't be used straight-forward. If you have enough resources and project is pretty big, you can translate that ideas into AvalonDock 2.0 world and publish it somewhere. That'd be huge for the community. =)